# Do I need to deal with WordPress SQL Injection

Tags: comments, sql, wp-insert-post

Do I need to prepare strings against MySQL Injection when inserting into the database using a WordPress comments function such as this:

```
$data = array(
    'comment_post_ID' => $post_id,
    'comment_author' => $comment_author,
    'comment_author_email' => $comment_email,
    'comment_content' => $comment_body,
    'comment_type' => '',
    'comment_parent' => 0,
    'user_id' => 1,
    'comment_author_IP' => '127.0.0.1',
    'comment_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 Firefox/3.0.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)',
    'comment_date' => $time,
    'comment_approved' => 1,
);

wp_insert_comment($data);
```

**Update:**
From [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) it seams as though it handles all of this, but doesn't strip HTML/PHP tags; is this in itself worth stripping on a purely security basis?

Answer (score 1):

Higher-level API functions like this in WP typically do the `$wpdb->prepare()` call to protect against MySQL injections.

As for content by default comments do allow HTML, however it isn't just anything. If you examine `default-filters.php` there are quite a few sanitizing functions hooked to processing comment data, including [`wp_kses_post()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_kses_post/) which limits HTML to white listed subset.